# problem:Website and Flash loading an older version of my SWF client

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a swf game client that's being hosted on my website. Users mostly use flash projector to connect directly by opening the swf's url. 
My problem is that, when I upload a newer version of this swf client on my website, the users still manage to load the older client, that is no longer there. older and newer clients had the same name, but I want to keep it that way. 
I would appreciate any suggestions :=)

Comment: Make the clent a loader that loads **"yourmainapp.swf?nocache=" + Math.random()** link to ensure the link is unique every time and the result is not cached by system or browser. More complicatedly, put a server-side script that outputs a unix **mtime** (last time modified timestamp) value for the given SWF file to cache result by version  **"yourmainapp.swf?nocache=" + mtime**.

Answer (score 0):

Like Organis's comment, here is one way to work out.

Your game will start from index.swf, and index.swf did't contain any game logic,its only job is to get the version number from index.html(use loaderInfo.parameters) and load the main game swf use the version num